# How can I choose a tab in a tabpanel without changing the card in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I have a tab panel with 3 tabs. The first tab is the general tab and has a tree with 2 types of nodes. When the user selects the first tab I want to show both types of nodes in the tree. When he selects the second or the third tab I want to hide away one type of node respectively. I do this by checking the beforetabchange event and removing nodes from the tree store and adding them back up. However, I do not want to change my 'card' in the tabpanel since all 3 tabs are supposed to show the same stuff. To achieve that, in my handler I return false in order to block the tab change. However this makes it so that the selected tab never changes and this causes problems. Is there a way to change tabs normally but keep one card active?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the desired behaviour you should either override `setActiveTab` method from `Ext.tab.Panel` or create a custom component extending `Ext.tab.Panel`.

Second alternative should be prefered since modifying a core component behaviour is not commonly desired. It will afect every single instance of it.

This is how creating your own component (extending from `Ext.tab.Panel` ) would look like:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.tab.CustomTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.customtabpanel',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    setActiveTab: function(card) {
        var me = this,
            previous;

        if(card) {
            previous = me.getActiveTab();

            me.tabBar.setActiveTab(card.tab);
            // we basically remove the part that changes between cards, 
            // but keep firing 'tabchange' event
            me.fireEvent('tabchange', me, card, previous);
        }            
    }
});
```

Then you can still listen to `'tabchange'` event to trigger your logic, but there will be no card changes.

I recreated a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/k5d) with your requirements, to show you how it would actually work. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: This solution worked for me indeed. I didn't want every tab to have this behavior so I added some extra logic, calling the function's parent wherever I needed to actually change the tabs. Thanks.